# How to use CanExecuteChangedEventManager

Tags: c#, wpf, events, weak-references

I can't figure out how to use the [CanExecuteChangedEventManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.canexecutechangedeventmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in `MyCommand : ICommand`.
I tried the following but `value` is the wrong type:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add
    {
        CanExecuteChangedEventManager.AddHandler(this, value);
    }
    remove
    {
        CanExecuteChangedEventManager.RemoveHandler(this, value);
    }
}
```

The class I'm writing will look like this but without leaks if possible:

```
public class ManualRelayCommand : ICommand
{
    // CanExecute() and Execute() excluded
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public virtual void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        var handler = CanExecuteChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => handler(this, EventArgs.Empty));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CanExecuteChangedEventManager is a class supporting weak event pattern. It is very common for controls developer to use weak events since you wish the controls not to have strong references to data.

CanExecuteChangedEventManager is used like this.

```
 public event EventHandler<EventArgs> CanExecuteChanged
 {
    add
    {
        CanExecuteChangedEventManager.AddHandler(this, value);
    }
    remove
    {
        CanExecuteChangedEventManager.RemoveHandler(this, value);
    }
 }
```

You need `EventHandler<EventArgs>` and that would be it.

If you still have questions about this feel free to ask :)

**Edit:**

You are not creating a control you are just creating a RelayCommand which inherits from ICommand.

You do not need `CanExecuteChangedEventManager`.

When you inherit from `ICommand` you must implement `public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;`

You can let it be that way without changing it. You dont change `PropertyChanged` event either do you? Just let it be there and it will work magically.

Controls who allow commanding know how to subscribe to that event. Just like PropertyChanged event from INotifyPropertyChanged interface. :)

Comment: I tried with `EventHandler<EventArgs>` but then VS complains I no longer implement ICommand.

Comment: That is another issue? Could you give me more code please. I am not sure what you are up to. Where did all of sudden ICommand came from? :) :) :)

Comment: Sorry man, I edited my question. I suck so hard at this I can't even ask a proper question :)

Comment: Its ok man. I edited my answer. You do not need to do anything. Just let it be the way it is.

Comment: Yes it works with the event like that. It was pointed out to me that it will leak though. I'll leave the question unanswered for a while until I understand this.

Comment: Ok :) If you have any questions let me know. Take a look at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Implemented it like this:

```
public class ManualRelayCommand
{
    ///...
    public override event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            InternalCanExecuteChangedEventManager.AddHandler(this, value);
        }
        remove
        {
            InternalCanExecuteChangedEventManager.RemoveHandler(this, value);
        }
    }
    private event EventHandler InternalCanExecuteChanged;
    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        EventHandler handler = InternalCanExecuteChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            if (_raiseCanExecuteOnDispatcher)
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => handler(this, new EventArgs())));
            }
            else
            {
                handler(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }
    private class InternalCanExecuteChangedEventManager : WeakEventManager
    {
        private static readonly InternalCanExecuteChangedEventManager Manager = new InternalCanExecuteChangedEventManager();
        static InternalCanExecuteChangedEventManager()
        {
            SetCurrentManager(typeof(InternalCanExecuteChangedEventManager), Manager);
        }
        internal static void AddHandler(ManualRelayCommand source, EventHandler handler)
        {
            Manager.ProtectedAddHandler(source, handler);
        }
        internal static void RemoveHandler(ManualRelayCommand source, EventHandler handler)
        {
            Manager.ProtectedRemoveHandler(source, handler);
        }
        ////protected override ListenerList NewListenerList()
        ////{
        ////    return new ListenerList();
        ////}
        protected override void StartListening(object source)
        {
            ((ManualRelayCommand)source).InternalCanExecuteChanged += DeliverEvent;
        }
        protected override void StopListening(object source)
        {
            ((ManualRelayCommand)source).InternalCanExecuteChanged -= DeliverEvent;
        }
    }
}
```